# Problem with lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

I have a question about a differential equation I tried to analyse:

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac {dx}{dt} &= v \\
\dfrac {dv}{dt} &= -x+x^3-v^3 \\
\end{align}
$$

I plotted this differential equation, and it looks like it has a spiral going inward (see picture). Now I tried to prove this: Therfore I searched a liapunov function and I think I found a local one:

$$  L = \dfrac 14(2v^2+2x^2-x^4)$$
for
$v^2+x^2 > \dfrac { x^4}2 $
and
$\dfrac {dL}{dt} = -v^4$

Now if I understand it right, the fixed point in the middle should attract all trajectories in the region where the lyapunov function is defined: $v^2+x^2 > x^4/2$
But if I compare the ‚region of attraction‘ of the lyapunov function with the computer simulation, it does not fit together.

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong? I appreciate every help!

[Region for Lyapunov function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pezr.jpg)

[Simulation with pplane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSYWa.jpg)

Comment: Your lyapunov candidate isn't positive definite on the set you are concerned with. Pick, for example, $v = \frac{5}{2}$ and $x = 2.$ Is there a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: Yes there was a mistake, thank you! I corrected it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write this as second order equation
$$
\ddot x+\dot x^3+x-x^3=0
$$
which can be interpreted as a one-dimensional kinetic system with potential force $x^3-x$ and a friction term $c(x,\dot x)\dot x$ with friction coefficient $c=\dot x^2$. Consequently it appears as reasonable to take the energy
$$
E(x,\dot x)=\frac12\dot x^2+\frac12x^2-\frac14x^4
$$
of the system as Lyapunov function, as you did.

The reasoning about the solutions crossing the level surfaces downwards is only correct as long as the level curves are concentric around the minimum. This region ends at the saddle points  $(x,\dot x)=(\pm 1,0)$. This gives the region
$$
E< \frac14\iff 2\dot x^2< (1-x^2)^2\iff \sqrt2|\dot x|< |1-x^2|
$$
The component containing the origin is
$$
\sqrt2|\dot x|+x^2< 1
$$
which looks rather compatible with your phase portrait.

Comment: Thank you very much! I arrived at this differential equation exactly by your reasoning. I tried to analyse a damped anharmonic oscillator. But I don’t exactly understand your argument ‚The reasoning about the solutions crossing the level surfaces downwards is only correct as long as the level curves are concentric around the minimum‘. What do you exactly mean with this or how do you arrive at this. I did not find this argument anywhere else.

Comment: The reasoning that $\frac{dL}{dt}=-\dot x^4\le 0$ implies a movement towards the center/minimum is only valid if the region you consider does not contain any other stationary points like the saddle points. The level curves around a minimum below such points are concentric "circles".

Comment: Ok I think I do now understand what’s the problem. But a last question: what do you mean with ‚level curves‘ or ‚level surface‘.

Comment: Curves in the phase plane where $E(x,\dot x)=C$ is constant. One can solve $y^2+x^2-\frac12x^4=R^2$ via $y=R\cos(\phi)$, $x\sqrt{1-\frac12x^2}=R\sin(\phi)$, the last can be solved for $x$ for $|x|<1$. This parametrization shows that these curves are bounded and closed.

Comment: @Lockhart By also using LaSalle's invariance principle one is only able to show that all trajectories that start in $\Omega=\{x,v\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,2(v^2+x^2)>x^4\}$ either converge to one of the equilibria (in general to the largest invariant set with $\dot{L}=0$) or leave $\Omega$. So one has to show that all trajectories at the boundary of $\Omega$ point into $\Omega$.

Comment: A common way of finding such set $\Omega$ is to use $\Omega=\{L\leq c\}$ and choose the largest possible $c$ for which the previous condition is still satisfied, which for this system and Lyapunov function indeed gives $c=1/4$. For more information see Nonlinear systems by H. Khalil, 2014, section 8.2.

Comment: The obtained $\Omega$ is often quite conservative. However, when skimming through that section it also mentions [Zubov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zubov%27s_method), which I believe should give the  basin of attraction exactly but is more difficult to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the main problem is, that my derivative of L is zero not only in the origin. And this would be the condition for a exponentially stable fixed point. So I also tried to find a Lyapunov function that is only zero at the origin. Sadly I failed at this. Do you have any guess for me? And I wonder why I can’t just exclude the points where dL/dt is zero from the definition space of L.

Comment: For example I tried $$L = \dfrac 12(a*v^2+2*b*v*x+c*x^2)+\dfrac 12x^2- \dfrac 14x^4$$. I could not find constants a,b and c to make this work.